# Is there a more concise way to extract (n > i) elements from an array?

Tags: c#

I need a piece of code that is capable of taking an array of strings of length `l`, extracting all of the elements that are present after `i`, where `i` is a particular index less than `l` and then placing the extracted elements into a new array.

Essentially if we have the below:

`["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]`

In this instance `l = 6` and if we take `n = 3` then the code should create a new array

`["D", "E", "F"]`

I've written the code out to do this, but I can't help think there's a better, more concise way to go about it.

Here's what I have:

```
List<string> tempElements = new List<string>();

for (int i = startOfMessage; i < elements.Length; i++)
{
    tempElements.Add(elements[i]);
}

string[] usableMessageElements = tempElements.ToArray();
```

A relatively simple problem, but I'm aiming to reduce as much junior code as I can.

Comment: 1) your code looks fine. 2) this is a better fit for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `string[] usableMessageElements = startOfMessage
   .Skip(startOfMessage)
   .ToArray();`

Comment: Conciseness is overrated IMO. I'd choose the more explanatory code over conciseness every time. 9/10 it is no less "efficient" to do something long handed. Not to mention the premature optimisation problem. Does this apply here, probably not but don't be conned into the assumption that short code is **always** good code.

Comment: The next c# will have some cool array stuff.  See the new array ranges:  https://blog.cdemi.io/whats-coming-in-c-8-0-ranges-and-indices/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2) from LINQ:

```
string[] usableMessageElements = elements.Skip(startOfMessage).ToArray();
```

Comment: What benefit does this bring over the existing code?

Comment: I guess it is more concise (as the OP asked for)

Comment: Removing the usage of the for loop and IList. Much more concise. Thanks Jon.

Comment: @Liam, seriously?  The title says, "Is there a more concise way?"  That is definitely more [concise](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concise): _Giving a lot of information clearly and in a few words; brief but comprehensive._

Comment: Yes @Idle_Mind seriously... o_O

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine but you can make use of Array.[Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int64_System_Array_System_Int64_System_Int64_):

```
 public string[] Extract(string[] source, int offset)
 {
        string[] strings = new string[source.Length - offset];
        Array.Copy(source, offset, strings, 0, strings.Length);
        return strings;
 }
 //...

 string[] usable = Extract(new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" }, 3); //D, E, F
```

Not very short but faster (1,000,000 iterations):

Adding to list: 226.0038 ms

Array Copy: 107.4445 ms

Comment: @Liam - It is shorter (2 lines) if you inline it in the same way as the question, and is more efficient than using `Skip` and `ToArray`.

Comment: Indeed not very short. I was going for performance here. Added some values for comparison

Comment: @Hyarus when giving benchmarks consider adding additional information about used architecture, pc specifications and so on.